# rxvt.exe is not in the folder after installing it through cygwin

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, urxvt, rxvt

I have installed `rxvt` using Cygwin.

The root directory is `F:\cygwin64`. So, after installing `rxvt`, `rxvt.exe` should be in `F:\cygwin64\bin` folder.

But I can't find it there. I have reinstalled it several times but no change. Why is this happening?

I'm using Windows 10 PC.

Comment: have you searched the system drive for it?

Comment: yes.. but can't find...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### So, after installing rxvt, rxvt.exe must be in "F:\cygwin64\bin" folder

The latest version of rxvt for cywin is `urxvt.exe` (where the `u` stands for Unicode):

> rxvt-unicode: An improved version of rxvt with Unicode support (installed binaries and support files)

On my system (64 bit Cygwin):

`urxvt.exe` is installed as `C:\cygwin\bin\urxvt.exe`.

In a `mintty` terminal you can use `which` to locate programs:

```
DavidPostill@Hal /f/test
$ which urxvtc.exe
/usr/bin/urxvtc.exe
```

...

```
DavidPostill@Hal /f/test
$ ll /usr/bin/urxvt*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 DavidPostill None 1191955 Jan  5 22:30 /usr/bin/urxvt.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 DavidPostill None   13331 Jan  5 22:30 /usr/bin/urxvtc.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 DavidPostill None      10 Jan  5 22:30 /usr/bin/urxvtc-X -> urxvtc.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 DavidPostill None 1197587 Jan  5 22:30 /usr/bin/urxvtd.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 DavidPostill None      10 Jan  5 22:30 /usr/bin/urxvtd-X -> urxvtd.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 DavidPostill None       9 Jan  5 22:30 /usr/bin/urxvt-X -> urxvt.exe
```

You can always find out what packages contain particular cygwin commands using [Search Packages](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi):

[image]

Clicking on https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Frxvt-unicode%2Frxvt-unicode-9.21-1&grep=rxvt:

> rxvt-unicode: An improved version of rxvt with Unicode support
>   (installed binaries and support files)
>
> ```
> 2015-10-20 22:15           0 usr/
> 2015-10-20 22:15           0 usr/bin/
> 2015-10-20 22:15           0 usr/bin/urxvt-X -> urxvt.exe
> 2015-10-20 22:15     1256989 usr/bin/urxvt.exe
> 2015-10-20 22:15           0 usr/bin/urxvtc-X -> urxvtc.exe
> 2015-10-20 22:15       13341 usr/bin/urxvtc.exe
> 2015-10-20 22:15           0 usr/bin/urxvtd-X -> urxvtd.exe
> 2015-10-20 22:15     1262621 usr/bin/urxvtd.exe
> 2015-10-20 22:15           0 usr/lib/
> 2015-10-20 22:15           0 usr/lib/urxvt/
> ```